# Basic C programming, printf function

Tags: c, printf

```
while (i) {
    printf("Digit (%d) = %d", d, ((num2/(pow(10,(i-1))))%10));
    d++;
    i--;
}
```

`i` and `d` are `int` values declared earlier on in the function. The error I'm getting is "`Operands of '%' have incompatible types 'double' and 'int'.`"

I keep getting this error message even after fiddling with the values.

Answer (score 7):

That is because `pow` returns a `double`.  You will have to typecast it.  Change the statement to:

```
printf("Digit (%d) = %d", d, ((int)(num2/(pow(10,(i-1))))%10));
```

Answer (score 3):

In alternative to casting the numerator into `int`, you could also call `fmod()` to perform modular computation in terms of floating point numbers.

```
printf("Digit (%d) = %lf", d, fmod((num2/(pow(10.0,(i-1)))),10.0));
```